Web3.js-sendSignedTransaction errors cannot be caught
I have a typescript function that receives signedTx hash as parameter and tries to call web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTx). In case signedTx is wrongly formatted, an error is thrown by web3.js. However, my try-catch block around the function call doesn't catch the error and this causes the program to crash. Neither the catch block or finally block is triggered.
Don't mind the this.saveTransaction line. I want to prevent the code from crashing. Does anyone know any tricks?
signedTx: 675836483638467384729847238476293720943729
async sendTransaction(
    nodeName: string,
    signedTx: string,
    userAgent: string,
  ): Promise<SendTransactionResponseDTO> {
    try {
      const web3 = await this.web3Service.getWeb3Instance(nodeName);
      const receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTx);
      const hash = receipt.transactionHash;
      await this.saveTransaction(signedTx, receipt, userAgent, nodeName);
      return {txId: hash.toString()};
    } catch (e) {
      this.logger.error(e);
      captureException(e);
      throw new HttpException('Dummy exception', 400);
    } finally {
      console.log("Finally")
    }
  }

node:internal/process/promises:391
    triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
    ^

Error: TypedTransaction with ID 103 unknown
    at TransactionFactory.fromSerializedData (/Users/dkdkdk/Documents/GitHub/self-api/node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/lib/commonjs/tx/transactionFactory.js:72:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/dkdkdk/Documents/GitHub/self-api/node_modules/web3-eth/lib/commonjs/rpc_method_wrappers.js:429:88)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/dkdkdk/Documents/GitHub/self-api/node_modules/web3-eth/lib/commonjs/rpc_method_wrappers.js:24:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/Users/dkdkdk/Documents/GitHub/self-api/node_modules/web3-eth/lib/commonjs/rpc_method_wrappers.js:20:12)
    at /Users/dkdkdk/Documents/GitHub/self-api/node_modules/web3-eth/lib/commonjs/rpc_method_wrappers.js:426:20
    at Immediate._onImmediate (/Users/dkdkdk/Documents/GitHub/self-api/node_modules/web3-eth/lib/commonjs/rpc_method_wrappers.js:499:16)
    at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:483:21)
    at process.topLevelDomainCallback (node:domain:160:15)

I tried to use .on().catch() instead of async-await, but still continued to crash.

you need to wait for tx to get tx errors, youre just sending the tx not waiting for it to be included in a block

i think its receipt.Wait() or WaitTx() something like that check intellisense
